# SQL- Write script to show project name and dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQl and just going through some exercises. I'm trying to do scripts but need some assistance and would appreciate if someone can help me with the below topic which I am stuck on.

**Table structure**

```
**Project**
    ID(PK)  NAME      Due_Date
    1       Alpha     1/1/2040
    2       Bravo     3/1/2030
    3       Charlie   2/1/2017
    4       Delta     4/1/2017

*Employee*
ID(PK)  NAME
1       Kevin
2       Mike
3       Eric
4       Ira
5       Peter

*Project Assignment*
ID(PK)  ProjectID(FK)   EmployeeID(FK)
1       1               1
2       1               2
3       2               2
4       2               3
5       3               3
6       3               4
7       1               3
```

***Question***
Write a script that will return all project names and how much time (in days) is left until they are due for all projects which have not been completed yet.

Comment: @Greggz.. Thanks - do you mind showing me how its done for my example?

Comment: @Sql_numskull [My post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311126/sql-write-script-to-show-project-name-and-dates/52311671#52311671) has been updated.

Comment: • @Greggz why does the OP have to create a SProc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is asked correctly, then you only need the projects table. But I doubt that is what you want.

```
SELECT Name, 
       DATEDIFF (DAY, GETDATE(), Due_Date) AS DaysRemaining
FROM Project
WHERE Due_Date > GETDATE()
```

If you need employee data included, please adjust your question.

Comment: If the due_date column is varchar, then cast is as date.

Comment: great.. makes sense.. I was over complicating because i saw the words scripts

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding i do this,

```
  select pa.ID,e.NAME,p.NAME,p.Due_Date, DATEDIFF (DAY, GETDATE(), Due_Date) AS 
  DaysRemaining from 
  Project_Assignment pa inner join project p
  on pa.projectid = p.id
  inner join Employe e
  on pa.EmployeeID = e.ID
  and p.due_date > getdate()
```

> Revert me any clarifications needed...

Comment: Thank you very much. This gives me the answers and more because it is joining on the employee as well. So it shows employee, project and days remaining

Comment: @Ranjiith - How would I edit this so I can only show completed projects?

Comment: @Sql_numskull Iam updated my query to your expectation.